# Zorba Installation

Tags: zorba

How to install Zorba in Ubuntu 12.04? When adding repository {using this command: **sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juan457/zorba**} , getting error 
"**Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources 404 Not Found**". 
can u suggest me how to clear this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most recent Zorba release (2.2) came out before Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin, so we didn't build packages for that Ubuntu version.

The next Zorba release (2.5) will be out within the next couple of days, so we will be updating the PPA binaries, including for Ubuntu 12.04.

You may be able to use the Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot packages in Ubuntu 12.04 by adding the following line to /etc/apt/sources.list:

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/juan457/zorba/ubuntu oneiric main

and then doing "sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install zorba". However I can't swear that will work; it's possible some dependent libraries will be different between the two Ubuntu releases.

Comment: Thanks for our suggestion, i'll check by installing 11.10 in my machine

Comment: @Chris Hillery: Have you guys stopped developing Zorba further for newer Ubuntu versions?

Comment: @madhavi I'm not sure there is a "you guys" anymore... a few developers are maintaining the websites as best they can, but the last code commit was nearly two years ago. The PPA is definitely unmaintained now. Still, I imagine the code should compile on more recent Ubuntu distributions without much trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Chris! I'll try to install the ppa on Ubuntu 16.04 ans see if it works. I need it to process JSONiq queries on linux, if you know any other alternative tool for the task, I'm all ears :)